# Trying to send a form to another domain inside Facebook iframe

Tags: php, facebook, forms, iframe, x-frame-options

Trying to send a form to another domain inside Facebook iframe on a Facebook app.

I have a form similar to this:

```
<form id="email_capture" action="{GOES TO ANOTHER DOMAIN}" method="POST">
                <input id="fname_capture_field" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" type="text">
                <input id="lname_capture_field" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" type="text">
                <input id="email_capture_field" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" type="text">
                <input id="phone_capture_field" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" type="text"><br/>
                <a id="email_capture_btn" href="#"></a>
                <p class="email_capture_error"></p>
            </form>
```

And it sends correctly if I go to the direct URL and use the form, but if I go through and use it as a Facebook app through an iframe, I get this error.

```
Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options
```

I've seen [this article already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options), but I don't have access to the other domain.

Any idea what I should do? Do I have to contact the other domain and get them to allow iframes?

Comment: if you not want to redirect user to external frame use jquery post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You contact other domain to let you display their page inside an iFrame or you use `_target` and change the page:

```
<form id="email_capture" action="{GOES TO ANOTHER DOMAIN}" method="POST" target="_top">
                <input id="fname_capture_field" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" type="text">
                <input id="lname_capture_field" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" type="text">
                <input id="email_capture_field" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" type="text">
                <input id="phone_capture_field" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" type="text"><br/>
                <a id="email_capture_btn" href="#"></a>
                <p class="email_capture_error"></p>
            </form>
```

Comment: Great idea, didn't know forms could have a target, I'll give it a shot.